# how to fix broadcom drivers for ubuntu touch?

Tags: drivers, kernel, ubuntu-touch, broadcom, samsung

How can i solve my issue to get ubuntu touch running on my phone?

I just create new defconfig for Ubuntu Touch to port on Galaxy S2 Plus, after compile it without problems, since my device doesn't support fastboot, i make a flashable version by taking a cm11 so i grab system folder of new image and replace it.

Here the following things are happen when trying to boot:

-only internal sdcard has been recognized by computer.
-shell access is worked and i was able to explore the phone from the computer.

after checking the syslog from recovery i found the Broadcom's gpu drivers crash after initializing, my questions are:
-is my gpu driver issue stop the boot?
-can i solve this problem from defconfig file of my kernel?

P.S: i follow janimo's phablet-porting-scripts to for the kernel, any help will welcome, thanx for all :) .

Best regard